# How do I calculate a duration time?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

I am developing a web-based application to capture start time and end time from system date-time but my main problem is that I don't know how can I get the duration time, between start and end time for downtime.

```
 //Function to get current start time
  var startTime = setInterval(function () { start() }, 1000);

  function start() {
    var startDate = new Date();
    var timeStart = startDate.toLocaleTimeString();
  $("#setCount").html(timeStart);
 }
```

Answer (score 51):

Do you mean this:

```
var date1 = new Date();
var date2 = new Date();
var diff = date2 - date1; //milliseconds interval
```

**upd**

check [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hVwX7/1/)

Comment: yes man ,but can i be able to get time that will start from the start of a downtime that will keep on counting until downtime finishes ?using your method ?

Comment: don't really get what you need there, but added link to JSFiddle, hope it'l help you

Answer (score 18):

**Update:**

If you want to display the time difference to user, [`Serigo's`](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1540859/sergio) [`method`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15493589/405398) will do it. But if it is for any development purposes, below functions will make your life easy.

---

Just wanted to let you know about this console utility functions.

Put this line in top of your app initialization code `console.time('appLifeTime');`

Put this one in where ever you feel that your app ends. `console.timeEnd('appLifeTime');`

```
console.time('appLifeTime');

setTimeout(function delay(){
  console.timeEnd('appLifeTime');
}, 1500);
```

The above code piece will print, `appLifeTime: 1500.583ms`.

AFAIK, `console.time & console.timeEnd` works in firefox(with firebug) & webkit browsers(chrome, safari).

Answer (score 9):

To simply measure time elapsed, use `Date.getTime()` which outputs current time in milliseconds since unix epoch.

You can substract one millis value from another to get the duration.

Example:

```
var startTime = new Date().getTime();

setTimeout(function () {
  var endTime = new Date().getTime();
  console.log("duration [ms] = " + (endTime-startTime));
}, 1500);
```

Output would be, of course: `duration [ms] = 1500` (or couple ms less or more).

Answer (score 7):

I have this function to show the time distance between two dates:

```js
export const timeDistance = (date1, date2) => {
  let distance = Math.abs(date1 - date2);
  const hours = Math.floor(distance / 3600000);
  distance -= hours * 3600000;
  const minutes = Math.floor(distance / 60000);
  distance -= minutes * 60000;
  const seconds = Math.floor(distance / 1000);
  return `${hours}:${('0' + minutes).slice(-2)}:${('0' + seconds).slice(-2)}`;
};
```

The output in the format `h:mm:ss` hours can grow arbitrary.

Answer (score 1):

Use this nifty jQuery plugin: http://timeago.yarp.com/

> Timeago is a jQuery plugin that makes it easy to support automatically
>   updating fuzzy timestamps (e.g. "4 minutes ago" or "about 1 day ago").
>   Download, view the examples, and enjoy.
>
> You opened this page about a minute ago. (This will update every
>   minute. Wait for it.)
>
> This page was last modified 13 days ago.
>
> Ryan was born 34 years ago.

Answer (score 0):

```
**Scripts:**

  function formatDate(difference) {
  
     //Arrange the difference of date in days, hours, minutes, and seconds format
     let days = Math.floor(difference / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
     let hours = Math.floor((difference % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
     let minutes = Math.floor((difference % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
     let seconds = Math.floor((difference % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);
     return "Total time elapsed is: " + days + " days " + hours + " hours " + minutes + " minutes " + seconds + " seconds.";
  }
  let start = new Date("December 31, 2020 23:59:59");
  let end = new Date();
  let difference = end - start;
  formatDate(difference);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
let output = document.getElementById('output');
      function formatDate(difference) {
      
         //Arrange the difference of date in days, hours, minutes, and seconds format
         let days = Math.floor(difference / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
         let hours = Math.floor((difference % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
         let minutes = Math.floor((difference % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
         let seconds = Math.floor((difference % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);
         output.innerHTML += "Total time elapsed is: " + days + " days " + hours + " hours " + minutes + " minutes " + seconds + " seconds.";
      }
      let start = new Date("December 31, 2020 23:59:59");
      let end = new Date();
      let difference = end - start;
      formatDate(difference);
```

```html
<h3> Using the <i> Date() object </i> to find the time elapsed in JavaScript </h3>
   <div id="output"></div>
```